# Why when <T extends Animal> casting List<List<Animal>> to List<List<T>> causes compilation error, but casting List<Animal> to List<T> causes warning?

Tags: java, generics

<sub>Question inspired by [Problem with casting a nested generic Set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74915567)</sub>

Simplified version of example from linked question:
<sub>(please don't focus on *purpose* of below methods, there is none - except for demonstration of the problem)</sub>

```
//class Animal may have subclasses like Dog, Cat, etc..

public static <T extends Animal> void foo(){
    List<List<Animal>> animalGroups = new ArrayList<>();
    List<List<T>> list = (List<List<T>>) animalGroups; //ERROR about incompatible types
}

public static <T extends Animal> void bar(){
    List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
    List<T> list = (List<T>) animals; //WARNING about unchecked cast
}
```

In above examples:

- inside `foo` method we get *compilation error* at `(List<List<T>>) animalGroups`,
- inside `bar` method we get only *warning* at `(List<T>) animals`.

#### Why compiler reacts differently on those situations?

##### Note:

Just to be cleared, I am NOT asking why those examples can't compile *without problems*.

I understand that [List<Dog> is NOT List<Animal>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265)

so code like

```
List<Dog> dogs = animals;
```

can't be allowed to compile because it would break type-safety, as we could add Cat to list of `animals` which means we would add that Cat to list of `dogs` (since `animals` and `dogs` would refer to same lists).

Also explicitly casting like

```
List<Dog> dogs = (List<Dog>) animals;
```

doesn't "convince" compiler that *we know what we are doing*, since we still would have same vulnerability in type-safety - Cat can still be added via `animals` to `dogs`.

---

##### My guess

We get warning instead of error in case of `(List<T>) animals` because there ***is a chance*** for such code to work safely. Specifically when `<T extends Animal>` will represent `Animal` type itself.

So if we call method bar like `MyClass.<Animal>bar();` inside it we would end up in situation like

```
List<Animal> list = (List<Animal>) animals;
```

which is fine (casting would be redundant, but allowed).

##### Problem with my guess

If my assumption is correct, then why casting `(List<List<T>>) animalGroups` gives us error instead of warning?

Same logic should be applied:

1. noticing that `<T extends Animal>` can take as value `Animal` type itself
2. noticing that in such case `List<List<Animal>> list = (List<List<Animal>>) animalGroups;` is fine.

BUT since results are different for `(List<T>) animals` and `(List<List<T>>) animalGroups` then IMO either

1. compiler doesn't analyze `T` in `List<List<T>>` like it does for `List<T>` (probably because it is part of *inner generic type*)
2. there really is a problem with `(List<List<T>>) animalGroups` that doesn't exist in `(List<T>) animals` and I missed it.

Comment: The problem here is that `List<Animal>` isn't compatible with `T`, since `T` extends Animal, not a List of Animal.  I can see why you hand-waved away the purpose of this code, since it seems unlikely that anyone would ever write code like this on purpose.

Comment: Same reason you can't cast `List<Cat>` to `List<Dog>`. `Cat` and `Dog` are distinct types, and so are `List<T>` and `List<Animal>`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "..since T extends Animal, not a List of Animal." please note that I am not casting `List<Animal>` to `List<List<T>>` nor `List<T>` to `List<List<Animal>>` but `List<List<Animal>>` to `List<List<T>>` and `List<Animal>` to `List<T>` (unless I misunderstood you).

Comment: @shmosel I am not convinced since case I referred to was when `<T extends Animal>` could represent `Animal` itself. So the `(List<List<T>>) listsOfAnimals` becomes equivalent of `List<List<Animals>> list = (List<List<Animals>>) listsOfAnimals;`. So there is case where both *inner* generic types are the same. So why warning in one case and error in other?

Comment: You can try looking at the JLS ([cast expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16) and [narrowing conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6) seem relevant). Honestly, from my reading, this looks like a `javac` bug (i.e. your suspicion is basically right and both cases should be a warning).

Comment: It doesn't matter that `T` is compatible with `Animal`. `Dog` is compatible with `Animal` but `(List<List<Dog>>)listsOfAnimals` is still an invalid cast, because `List<Animal>` and `List<Dog>` are unrelated types.

Comment: @HTNW I found that in [5.1.10. Capture Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10) there is a part that states "Capture conversion is not applied recursively" but based on [What is a capture conversion in Java and can anyone give me examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4431702) I assume it applies for wildcards like `<? ..>`. I am not sure if it also applies to `<T ...>` (if it is then question is solved, but will need to find JLS part which states that)

Comment: @shmosel No, it does matter. The cast `(List<T>)listOfAnimals` is permitted exactly because (see my JLS links) it is possible that `T = Animal` and therefore the cast isn't "stupid" (always wrong) like `(List<Dog>)listOfAnimals` (There exists a narrowing reference conversion from `List<T>` to `List<Animal>` because (various supertypes of) these types are not provably distinct, and this because `T` is not provably distinct from `Animal`.) So the question is, why does the same reasoning not allow `(List<List<T>>)listsOfAnimals`, since in the case `T = Animal` this cast is also not wrong?

Comment: @shmosel True, which is why compiler doesn't "like it". But since that problem exist in *both* casts: `(List<T>) animals` and `(List<List<T>>) listsOfAnimals` why are they treated differently by compiler?

Comment: I think top-level generic casting is treated as a special case. I'm more curious why `(ArrayList<T>)animals` doesn't produce a warning.

Comment: @shmosel That may be worth creating separate question :)

Comment: bar succeeds if T is a subtype of Animal, foo succeeds if and only if T is Animal, so writing it generic is nonsense, why not forbid it?

Comment: And I think your suspicion is wrong, the compiler allows the casting because all elements of a List<Animal> might be Ts, not because T might be Animal

Comment: @Turo I fully agree that those examples doesn't seem to have any use in current form. But like I said at start of the question, they ware inspired by other question and there author explained his real world use-case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74915567/problem-with-casting-a-nested-generic-set#comment132207519_74915567. Anyway "foo succeeds if and only if T is Animal" problem is that *it doesn't* since compiler decides to generate error here in contrast to `bar` where it generates *warning*.

Comment: @Turo "*...I think your suspicion is wrong, the compiler allows the casting because all elements of a List<Animal> might be Ts, not because T might be Animal*" I also though about it initially, but if that would be true, then compiler would also allow `List<Dog> dogs = (List<Dog>) animals;` (maybe with *warning*) but here it generates *error*. It doesn't consider possibility that `animals` *may only hold `Dog`* instances. IMO error in such case is correct because it compiler *knows* it creates vulnerability in type-safety, because via `animals` we could add `Cat` to such `List<Dog> dog`.

Comment: Oh, paint my tongue black, your right!

Answer (score 2):

This is java working intended, because that's what generics *mean*, as you evidently already understand (the wonky nature of variance means that allowing `List<Animal> = listOfDogs;` lets you add cats to your list of dogs and that's no good - why generics are invariant in a nutshell), and, crucially, *because generics are a figment of `javac`'s imagination*!

Java did not ship with generics. Until java 1.5, generics just weren't a thing. At all. We just wrote:

```
/**
 * Adopts a {@link com.foo.animals.Dog dog}; a dog will be taken from the kennel and added to your list of pets.
 * @param list List of pets.
 */
void adoptDog(List pets) { ... }
```

i.e. the notion that `pets` is to be treated as a list of animals is figured out based on documentation and context clues from the names of things alone, and by 'following the links' - i.e. realizing that `Dog` is defined as `extends Animal`, therefore one may **assume** that adopting a few dogs into a newly made list means any code that assumes that `pets` contains only instances of `Animal` will be fine.

java1.5 introduced generics, but generics are *100% an all-javac show* - it is merely making it official: **Compiler-checked documentation**. Literally: The JVM spec (JVM Specification, i.e. `java.exe`) *has no idea what generics are*. Javac eliminates most of it; the few places where it makes it into a class file are places java.exe *completely ignores*. I does what the spec says it should do with them: It knows how to read them (otherwise it wouldn't be able to even understand the class file at all), but it just skips right past this stuff.

When you write this:

```
class Foo<T extends Bar> {
  public <Z super Foo> void foo() {}
}
```

The generics *do* make it into the class file, but the *only* reason they do, is because `javac` can run based on a mix of source files *and* class files, and it needs to know the generics in those class files to do its magic.

A bit of code you should play around with:

### Javac injects casts for you, and java.exe doesn't care about corruption

You cannot make java compile this code:

```
void foo(String str) {
  int foo = str;
}
```

as in, somehow attempt to assign the memory location/compressed ref that `str` is under the hood / at the JVM level, and directly access it as an `int` (or these days, on 64-bit arch, a `long` perhaps). You can certainly try to manipulate your class file and edit bytecode to do it though:

```
NB: Not real bytecode, just serves to explain the idea

PUSH // push a string ref from the constant pool
POPI 1 // pop the top of the stack into an int-typed local var slot
```

But if you try this, the moment that class file is loaded, you would get a `ClassVerifierError`. The JVM actually takes some effort (and the JVM Spec demands it do this) to ensure such shenanigans aren't in there. If they are, the entire class file itself is flat out rejected.

In contrast, if you try to pull the precise same stunt with generics, **java.exe does not care whatsoever** and will gladly run it. That's because `javac` -itself- does this. There are no generics at runtime. This:

```
void foo(List<String> list) {
  return list.get(0).toLowerCase();
```

is compiled to the exact same bytecode as:

```
void foo(List list) { // raw type - anything goes.
  return ((String) list.get(0)).toLowerCase();
```

Try it! Run `javap -c -v CompiledClassFile` to see the bytecode.

The only difference at the bytecode level between those two is *one* slight change: The fact that the param's type is `List<String>` *is* stored in the classfile; not that the JVM has any clue as to what that might mean. But `javac` does, and will take it into account if javac attempts to compile some code that calls this `foo` method.

So why is this completely fine and not a security leak, whereas the attempt to 'pop' a string ref into an int variable is so egregiously bad the JVM takes the time to scan the class bytecode, find this, and reject the entire file?

Because `javac` --injected-- that cast, and casts *are* things the JVM itself (`java.exe`) knows about, rigorously applies, and this therefore prevents core dumps or other sorts of severe heap corruption; if you finagle your way to call this method with a list containing a non-string, you simply get a `ClassCastException`. Let's try it!

```
List list = new ArrayList(); // raw warning, we'll ignore it.
list.add(Integer.valueOf(5)); // not a string!
foo(list);
```

The above code will throw a ClassCastException. Weirdly, it is thrown on a line *that does not contain any casts at all*. That's because javac inserted it. `javac` *will* compile it, and `java.exe`'s verifier will be totally fine with it.

Javac also applies, purely as a compiler move, a check; if you attempt to invoke the `foo` method and pass it a `List<Integer>` for example, `javac` itself will refuse to compile it and emit an error. **But that is all** - javac simply refuses. It *could* produce legal bytecode that a JVM will accept and run. If the list was empty, you'd never know it was broken. If it's not empty, well, that ClassCastException occurs which isn't a security or heap corruption issue. Exceptions are 'safe', they don't cause core dumps, memory corruption, potential avenues for buffer overruns, etcetera. If you patch javac to not complain, then the byte code produced would be fine (likely to throw an exception if you invoke it, but that's fine).

> is that compiler allows casting in case where there is a chance for such code to work safely.

As far as generics is concerned, correct, but doesn't explain what you're witnessing here. That's just as a convenience to you. Why let you write code that makes no sense? That's just enabling you to write bugs.

> `(List<List> someListOfListsOfAnimals) // compiler error

Yeah, that's a weird one, isn't it? You can always force the issue. This compiles:

```java
List<List<Animal>> a = new ArrayList<>();
List /* raw */ temp = a;
List<List<T>> b = (List<List<T>>) temp;
```

We can even combine those casts into this monster:

```
List<List<T>> a = (List<List<T>>) listOfListsOfAnimals; // error!
List<List<T>> a = (List<List<T>>) (List) listOfListsOfAnimals; // warning!
```

That second line, whilst looking pretty stupid, actually 'works' (compiles; it's still a warning; anytime you tell javac to buzz off about generics you get a warning because javac is the first and last line of defense on these things; if javac is told not to care about it, nothing will, hence, javac tells you: Ooookay mate, you're on your own then, here, a warning to make doubly sure you fully understand your promises on this stuff is the *only* thing stopping some very bizarro bugs from showing up in your code base!).

So, why? It's mostly 'because the spec says so'. "Why does the spec say so"? Because.. it does, at some point you're asking: What were the authors of that spec thinking about when they wrote it, which, given that they didn't maintain an official diary when they did, is unanswerable except possibly by the authors themselves, which do not, as far as I know, frequent Stack Overflow.

One can guess, perhaps. With 'raw' it is allowed because 'raw' mode allows anything, that's sort of the point of raw mode. Looking solely at what's in the generics, you're trying to cast `List<Animal>` to `List<T>` and those types have no relationship at all (because generics are invariant, hence, these are as different from each other as `Integer` and `String` are - neither is a supertype of the other). The spec simply says that casting siblings (unrelated types) to each other isn't allowed. So, for the same line of spec that dictates this:

```
Integer i = ...;
String s = (Integer) i;
```

is to be considered a compiler error because it's non-sensical, now your cast is also flagged down as a straight error even though here it's less clear, given that even though the types are nominally 100% unrelated, it sure feels utterly bizarre that `List<List<T>>` where T is defined as `T extends Animal`, and `List<List<Animal>>` are completely unrelated and therefore one cannot be cast to the other like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (sorry for late comment, it is not that easy to read/"digest" answer and answer comments in other places). Please give me some time. Anyway in "*therefore one may **assume** that adopting a few dogs into a newly made list means any code that assumes that `pets` contains only instances of `Animal` will be fine.*" I assume you meant "*...that `pets` contains only instances of `Dog` will be fine.*" (even if `Dog` is technically `Animal`).

Comment: The first half of this answer seems irrelevant: it explains why the casts in the question are unsafe (so why both should at least be warnings) and OP knows this. The second half appears at least a little wrong. First, the spec isn't magic, and its intents are often pretty transparent. (It even has little notes in it explaining its decisions!) Second, my reading of the spec tells me that *it specifies both casts in the question to be warnings*. It would be nice if you could back up "the spec says so" (I would love to be told `javac` doesn't have a bug!).

Comment: @Pshemo yes, either way - let's say I later hand the same list to `adoptCat`, the point is, before generics the only way to know what type of object was in your list is by checking what you yourself added to it, as well as what the docs say of any methods you gave your list to. _With_ generics, same thing, really, except now it's `javac` that does this checking for you. Point is, it's still a separate check and one that you can 'break' by playing fast and loose - e.g. by ignoring those warnings. In contrast to `Dog foo = method();` where `foo` __cannot__ be referring to a cat. Period.

Comment: Again thank you for your answer. Regarding the though "why bother using such code" no worries, I never needed nor plan to use it. But since IMO it was interesting phenomenon I saw somewhere else I decided to ask about it, maybe someone else will also find it interesting. Also I realize that I will not get full answer with every single though of author. But JLS is also fine. Bonus points if it will include *some* reasoning which makes sense, since JLS author may have *many* reasons to write it that way, I just need *one* which will let me *understand* such decision instead of *remembering* it.

Comment: Probably 'before 1.5, we wrote into the langspec that a 'sibling cast' (Going from e.g. String to Integer) is illegal because why not - and after generics were introduced, where a sibling cast can nevertheless make sense, nobody bothered to complicate the sibling cast rule, nor did anybody decide to get rid of it.'